# Import a project as different name in same workspace in eclipse indigo .It shows already available

Tags: eclipse

Export a project as file system into some location and changed the name. Import that project from that location into same workspace in Eclipse Indigo. It shows already available in that project so I can't import a project. What is the solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just changing the name of the exported folder or zip file does not change the project name as far as Eclipse is concerned.

To change the project name that Eclipse uses you would have to edit the `.project` file in the project root directory. This is an XML file, the `<name>` tag defines the project name:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>project name</name>
    .... other stuff ....
</projectDescription>
```